# How to animate Table Item Entry using TransitionGroup and Material UI Tables in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am having an issue where I can't seem to get `TransitionGroup` to work with `Material UI ReactJS` library

My expectation is pretty simple, upon entry into the table the row should be animated in like sliding into the table.

I have tried the following but this only end up scattering the table, the headers and everything becomes out of shape.

Here is what I have tried using the `Material UI` library for `ReactJS`

```
                   <TableContainer>
                        <Table aria-label="stats-table">
                            <TableHead>
                                <TableRow>
                                   {...}
                                </TableRow>
                            </TableHead>
                            <TransitionGroup
                                transitionName="fade"
                                transitionEnterTimeout={1000}
                                transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
                                transitionAppearTimeout={1000}
                                transitionAppear={true}
                                component="tbody">
                                <TableBody>
                                    {
                                        (rowsPerPage > 0 ? games.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage) : games
                                        ).map((row: Game) => (
                                            <SimpleTableRow row={row} key={row.id}/>
                                        ))}
                                    {
                                        emptyRows > 0 && (
                                            <TableRow style={{height: 53 * emptyRows}}>
                                                <TableCell colSpan={6}/>
                                            </TableRow>
                                        )
                                    }
                                </TableBody>
                            </TransitionGroup>
                   </TableContainer>
```

The moment I add the TransitionGroup, the entire table headers and body becomes scattered.

How can I make this work? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but try putting the `TransitionGroup` be inside of the `map` around each `SimpleTableRow` rather than around the entire `TableBody`.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I tried your suggestion and I still get same issue. The entire table becomes scattered...The headers are shifted to the right and the body shifted to the left...

Comment: Having the same error. By inserting the transition elements inbetween, whole row moves to the first column of the table. By wrapping the cell content, it works but the rows borders are keept. Still looking for a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass `component={null}` instead `component="tbody"`.